# Convergence of method for optimization on manifold $SO(3)$?

Tags: probability, optimization, riemannian-geometry, haar-measure

Let $f\colon SO(3)\to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded countinuous founction.
I want to solve the optimization problem
$$\min_{R\in SO(3)}f(R).$$
Since I am not interested in very good performance and too accurate results, I am approximate it by the following method: Let $R_i\sim U(SO(3))$ be i.i.d samples from the (uniform) Haar measure distribution of $SO(3)$, which we denote by $U(SO(3))$. I just calculate $\min(R_1,\cdots,R_N)$ and the results look quite right to the one reference I have. But is there any reference, where it states that it really converges and which converges do we have then? More precisely, do we have
$$\min\{f(R_1),\dots,f(R_n)\}\overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\min_{R\in SO(3)}f(R)=:f_{min}.$$
Intuitively it makes, since the function is continuous and for all $\epsilon>0$ there should exists a compact non-empty neighborhood $V$ of the argument of the minimum such that all elements in $V$ evaluated by the function $f$ are at least $\epsilon$ different from minimum, i.e. $|f(R)-f_{min}|<\epsilon$ for all $R\in V$. So for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a probability of $0<\mu(V)/\mu(SO(3))<1$ such that $|f(\tilde{R})-f_{min}|<\epsilon$ with $\tilde{R}\sim U(SO(3))$ ($\mu$ is the Haar measure of $SO(3)$). The problem I am not so good in the topic of manifold optimization and I am not very used to the Haar measure.

Comment: If you sample $n$ times and each sample has probability $p$ to be distance $<\epsilon$ from the minimum, then the probability that _no_ sample is distance $<\epsilon$ from the minimum is $(1-p)^n$. You have:
$$P(|\min (f(R_1),...,f(R_n) ) - \min_R f(R)| ≤\epsilon) = 1- (1-p)^n$$
as $n\to\infty$ this goes to $1$. So your approximation will almost surely (in the sense of probability theory) converge to $\min_R f(R)$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thank for your comment. I have just two questions: 1) Do you have any idea how I prove that there exists a positive probability $p$ that each sample has distance $<\epsilon$ from the minimum? 2) Is the convergences you gave not convergence in probability, in the sense that $$P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)\to 0$$ as $n\to\infty$ for all $\epsilon >0 $?

Comment: Since $f$ is continuous and $SO(3)$ is compact there is an $\overline R$ with $f(\overline R) =\inf_R f(R)$. Again by continuity for every $\epsilon$ there is a neighbourhood $N$ of $\overline R$ for which you have $f(N) \subseteq f(\overline R) + [-\epsilon, \epsilon]$. Since $N$ is a neighbourhood it has positive Haar measure, so you get $p≥\mu(N)>0$ (assume the Haar measure is normalised). The resulting convergence is indeed nothing other than convergence in probability.

Comment: Thank you! It sounds good.